# How to query realtime database properly for cloud fucntion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

**UPDATED**

I am trying to query my pricing data based on the user it is saved under and send it back in my stripe checkout cloud function. It keeps giving me an error stating that no value has been assigned to my variables when I have. I read the docs on how to do this, but I kinda got confused towards the end. I then saw something similar to what I was trying to do on a couple of other places, but then I got the codes mixed up. How can I call the variable names from the other function to put them in the pricing info?

Sources I used:

- [How to query specific data from Firebase using Cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280341/how-to-query-specific-data-from-firebase-using-cloud-functions)
- [How to run query from inside of Cloud function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868592/how-to-run-query-from-inside-of-cloud-function)
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

This is how my data is set up in my real time database:

```
studiopick
   studio
     users
        Gcsh31DCGAS2u2XXLuh8AbwBeap1
          email : "Test@gmail.com"
          firstName : "Test"
          lastName : "one"
          phoneNumber : "2223334567"
          prices
          |   roomA
          |     serviceOne
          |       numberInput : "300"
          |       serviceType : "mix n master"
           studioName : "Studio One"
           uid : "Gcsh31DCGAS2u2XXLuh8AbwBeap1"
```

This is how my cloud function is set up:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

let price;
let info;

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createStripeCheckout = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const querySnapshot = await ref
    .orderByChild("numberInput, serviceInput")
    .equalTo(price, info)
    .once("value");
  // Stripe init
  const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret_key);
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: "http://localhost:5500/success",
    cancel_url: "http://localhost:5500/cancel",
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ["US"],
    },
    line_items: [
      {
        quantity: 1,
        price_data: {
          currency: "usd",
          unit_amount: price * 100, // 10000 = 100 USD
          product_data: {
            name: info,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  return {
    id: session.id,
  };
});

exports.stripeWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.token);
  let event;

  try {
    const whSec = functions.config().stripe.payments_webhook_secret;

    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      req.rawBody,
      req.headers["stripe-signature"],
      whSec
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("⚠️ Webhook signature verification failed.");
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  }

  const dataObject = event.data.object;

  await admin.firestore().collection("orders").doc().set({
    checkoutSessionId: dataObject.id,
    paymentStatus: dataObject.payment_status,
    shippingInfo: dataObject.shipping,
    amountTotal: dataObject.amount_total,
  });

  return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions run in their own isolated containers when deployed.

When you call your `retreivefromdatabase` function, an instance of your Cloud Functions code is spun up, then the request is handled and the instance hibernates when it finishes (and it will be shut down later if not called upon again). When you call your `createStripeCheckout` function, a new instance of your Cloud Functions code is spun up, then the request is handled and the instance hibernates (and shuts down later).

Because these functions are hosted and handled by separate instances, you can't pass information between functions using global state.

Unfortunately the local testing emulator doesn't completely isolate functions in the same way (nor does it emulate [throttling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#do_not_start_background_activities)), which is what misled you to believe that it should function just fine in production.

Comment: Ohhh wow ok. Is there another way I can get the price from my realtime db or I can't send any information to stripe at all?

Comment: You would pass `numberInput` and `serviceType` directly into the `createStripeCheckout` function. If needed, query the database first in the `createStripeCheckout` function. `const querySnapshot = await ref.orderByChild("numberInput, serviceInput").equalTo(price, info).once("value")`

Comment: Like this? I have updated my fucntion